# If value bigger than 0 mark line green

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula

I have made a guest list sheet in Google Sheets with two columns, one of name and one of attendance. The attendance column can have two values, either `X` (when people don't come) or a number (mostly `1` or `2`, but safe to say always bigger than 0).

I've already created a custom formula marking the whole line (including the name) red if there is an `X` in the second column.

[image: X marks line red]

[image: Spreadsheet with red lines]

This formula works like a charm!

I now want to do the same thing, but making the whole line (including the name) green if there is a number placed in the column. I've tried replacing the `X` in the custom formula with `1`, `2`, `3` etc (also with colons and semi-colons) but that doesn't work.

Does any of you know what I need to do?

Comment: What's wrong with `> 0`?

Answer (score 0):

Please select ColumnsA:C and: Format > Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... Custom formula is and:

```
=and(isnumber($C1),$C1<>0)
```

with green fill for Formatting style and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

(Assumes `2` etc are Number format.)